# How to manage labels in Gmail with keyboard?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, gmail-labels

At work we use Google Apps. I like to assign mails that are important to my work with `todo` and after I did them with `done`. I am pondering a way to do this efficiently and preferably without the usage of a mouse. Right now I have a label system like:

```
!Work > Todo >
!Work > Todo > Done
```

Yet here the problem is that I will also see the done-mails when I am looking for some I want to do next. Also I find myself dragging and dropping labels onto the mails, which I find tiresome.

Is there a way to use the keyboard instead?

Comment: Another way is to use the [GTD Firefox Extension](http://lifehacker.com/369590/get-things-done-in-gmail-with-gtdinbox) (there is probably a Chrome one btw)

Comment: @dnbrv Why did you rename the title? I know how to handle labels manually, yet I do not know to the handle todo- and done-labels properly.

Comment: Because your labels are custom, which makes your question too localized. I'm actually going to edit the title again to make it more descriptive.

Comment: @dnbrv I would argue that "Todo" and "Done" labels are too localized. But I can live with the reedit.

Comment: Although some other people may use those labels, they *aren't standard* in GMail. Any customizations make your situation localized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First turn on  [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6594):

> To turn these case-sensitive shortcuts on or off, click the gear icon 
>   at the top of any Gmail page and then Mail settings. Choose the option
>   next to "Keyboard shortcuts" to turn them on. You can also enable
>   shortcutsautomatically by going to http://mail.google.com/mail/?kbd=1

After selecting an email use <kbd>L</kbd>, it opens the labels menu to label a conversation.

Type the label you want.

Another cool step is to:

1. open up the todo label,
2. then use the <kbd>L</kbd> shortcut key to add the done label,
3. then use the <kbd>Y</kbd> shortcut key to remove the todo label.

The result is that it will only be under the done label.

Comment: Is it possible to activate the *Move* menu to move a conversation?

Comment: Yes, use `v` instead of `l` to open the menu.